# Which design pattern fits best to avoid multiple parameters in method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have the following class:

```
public class SomeAssebler {

    private EnrichedRequest assembleBasicEnrichedRequest(BasicRequest request) {
        EnrichedRequest enrichedRequest = new EnrichedRequest();
        if (request != null) {
            enrichedRequest.setId(request.getId());
            enrichedRequest.setDate(request.getDate());
            enrichedRequest.setParam(request.getParam());
        }
        return enrichedRequest;
    }

    private static EnrichedRequest assembleGeoDataEnrichedRequest(EnrichedRequest request, GeoData geoData) {
        EnrichedRequest geoEnrichedRequest = Optional.ofNullable(request).orElse(new EnrichedRequest());
        if (geoData != null) {
            geoEnrichedRequest.setCity(geoData.getCity());
            geoEnrichedRequest.setCountryCode(geoData.getCountryCode());
        }
        return geoEnrichedRequest;
    }

    private static EnrichedRequest assembleUserAgentEnrichedRequest(EnrichedRequest request, UserAgentData userAgentData) {
        EnrichedRequest userAgentEnrichedRequest = Optional.ofNullable(request).orElse(new EnrichedRequest());
        if (userAgentData != null) {
            userAgentEnrichedRequest.setBrowser(userAgentData.getBrowserCode());
            userAgentEnrichedRequest.setOperatingSystem(userAgentData.getOsCode());
            userAgentEnrichedRequest.setManufacturer(userAgentData.getBrand());
        }
    }

    public static EnrichedRequest assembleEnrichedRequest(BasicRequest request, GeoData geoData, UserAgentData userAgentData) {
        EnrichedRequest enrichedRequest = assembleBasicEnrichedRequest(request);
        enrichedRequest = assembleGeoDataEnrichedRequest(enrichedRequest, geoData);
        enrichedRequest = assembleUserAgentEnrichedRequest(enrichedRequest, userAgentData);
        return enrichedRequest;
    }
}
```

It is then called in different transformers: 
In the GeoDataTransformer

```
new KeyValue<>(key, assembleEnrichedRequest(basicRequest, geoData, null))
```

In the UserAgentTransformer:

```
new KeyValue<>(key, assembleEnrichedRequest(enrichedRequest, null, userAgent))
```

If more "enrichers" will be added in the future this can get very ugly.
Anyone has an idea how I can design this better? 
I though of the Builder design pattern but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Builder Pattern`, but you have to do a couple of changes in your code.

You can check from this [link](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder) which explains how you will use the builder pattern and what it solves. You can try something like that there are lots of different ways to create a `Builder` class.

```
public static class EnrichedRequestBuilder() {
    private EnrichedRequest enrichedRequest:
    private BasicRequest basicRequest:
    private GeoData geoData;
    private UserAgentData userAgentData;

    public EnrichedRequestBuilder enrichedRequest(EnrichedRequest e) {
        this.enrichedRequest = e;
        return this;
    }

    public EnrichedRequestBuilder basicRequest(BasicRequest e) {
        this.basicRequest = e;
        return this;
    }

    public EnrichedRequestBuilder build() {
        return new EnrichedRequestBuilder(this);
    }


}

new EnrichedRequestBuilder().basicRequest(b).enrichedRequest(e).build();
```

Comment: I did end up using the Builder Pattern after all, you are right there are many ways to implement this pattern and I guess that's why I was confused. I also did it a bit different than what you proposed, but you helped in the right direction.